# sysctlbyname error Implicit declaration of function 'sysctlbyname' is invalid in C99

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios7

I am getting an error "Implicit declaration of function 'sysctlbyname' is invalid in C99" when i used this code. I used it before and it was fine so I don't know what happen.

I am currently developing for iOS7 devices only and using the latest ver of xcode 5 that is on the app store

UIDeviceHardware.m

```
@interface UIDeviceHardware : NSObject

- (NSString *) platform;
- (NSString *) platformString;

@end
```

UIDeviceHardware.m

```
- (NSString *) platform{
    size_t size;
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", NULL, &size, NULL, 0);
    char *machine = malloc(size);
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", machine, &size, NULL, 0);
    NSString *platform = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:machine];
    free(machine);
    return platform;
}

- (NSString *) platformString{
    NSString *platform = [self platform];
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,1"])    return @"iPhone 1G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,2"])    return @"iPhone 3G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone2,1"])    return @"iPhone 3GS";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,1"])    return @"iPhone 4 (GSM)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,3"])    return @"iPhone 4 (CDMA)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone4,1"])    return @"iPhone 4S";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,1"])    return @"iPhone 5 (GSM)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,2"])    return @"iPhone 5 (GSM+CDMA)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,3"])    return @"iPhone 5c (GSM)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,4"])    return @"iPhone 5c (GSM+CDMA)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone6,1"])    return @"iPhone 5s (GSM)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone6,2"])    return @"iPhone 5s (GSM+CDMA)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone7,1"])    return @"iPhone 6 GSM";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone7,2"])    return @"iPhone 6 GSM+CDMA";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone8,1"])    return @"iPhone 6+ GSM";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone8,2"])    return @"iPhone 6+ Global";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod1,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 1G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod2,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 2G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod3,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 3G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod4,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 4G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod5,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 5G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad1,1"])      return @"iPad";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,1"])      return @"iPad 2 (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,2"])      return @"iPad 2 (GSM)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,3"])      return @"iPad 2 (CDMA)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,4"])      return @"iPad 2 (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,5"])      return @"iPad Mini (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,6"])      return @"iPad Mini (GSM)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,7"])      return @"iPad Mini (GSM+CDMA)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,1"])      return @"iPad 3 (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,2"])      return @"iPad 3 (GSM+CDMA)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,3"])      return @"iPad 3 (GSM)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,4"])      return @"iPad 4 (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,5"])      return @"iPad 4 (GSM)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,6"])      return @"iPad 4 (GSM+CDMA)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,1"])      return @"iPad Air (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,2"])      return @"iPad Air (GSM)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,4"])      return @"iPad Mini Retina (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,5"])      return @"iPad Mini Retina (GSM)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"i386"])         return @"Simulator";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"x86_64"])       return @"Simulator";
    return platform;
}
```

Comment: any update on iphone6 and iphone6+ ?

Comment: @esskar
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone7,1"])    return @"iPhone 6 GSM";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone7,2"])    return @"iPhone 6 GSM+CDMA";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone8,1"])    return @"iPhone 6+ GSM";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone8,2"])    return @"iPhone 6+ Global";

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Maybe my answer is trivial, but, Did you include `sys/sysctl.h`?

`#import <sys/sysctl.h>`